# if statement php?

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know why but this is not working:

I am working on an Ajax send , i have send a value to a PHP script which parses the values and store the values in a php variable.
and now:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = $_GET['url'];
$check = $_GET['check'];
$filid = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$filurl = mysql_real_escape_string($url);



if($check == 'true'){
    $insert  = "INSERT INTO tab (id,url) VALUES ('$filid','$filurl')";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I am confirmed that my Ajax code is working , i'm not sure about php.When i remove the if statement and directly put the data into my database , it's working.

I'm new so please tolerate.
I hope someone can point me out my mistakes are.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `$_GET['check']` actually contain?

Comment: Add var_dump($_GET['check']); to see if you are getting 'true'

Comment: This code has a horrible security hole.

Comment: see `var_dump($check)` before `if` and post it here

Comment: What's the value of `check` and where does it come from?

Comment: Can you post the details of the ajax call? Are you sending the variables via POST instead of GET?

Comment: On a sidenote: use `mysql_real_escape_string` before you insert GET values into your tables. This code is prone to SQL injection: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: can you a var_dump($_GET) before the if statement just to be sure what is exactly being sent.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for the security sql injection issue

Comment: @Konard. Not if php is patched to quote/strip user parameters before adding them to global. :)

Comment: Yes i know mysql_real_escape_string , i ahevnt added it yet because im testing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Please dear God!  I can't believe that none of the answers so far have pointed out the *massive* SQL injection vector in the original code; to be honest it's better for the safety of your database that the if block isn't working as you originally intended!

You *must* sanatize, escape and clean up *all* data that comes from the user; failing to do this will leave your database wide open for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  If this is new to you then I suggest you read up on [some articles](http://www.php-developer.org/best-practices-when-sanitizing-post-to-prevent-mysql-and-xss-attacks/) and possibly invest in [a book on the subject](http://phpsecurity.org/).

PHP includes a function which will sanatize values for you called [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), you should modify your SQL statement to read:

```
$clean_id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$clean_url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);

$insert  = "INSERT INTO tab (id,url) VALUES ('$clean_id','$clean_url')";
```

To avoid having to remember such things I suggest you look into database abstraction layers which will handle this for you; [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) is a popular package although there are plenty of others out there such as [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: Oh dear god. im not asking this. i know mysql_real_escape_string , i havent added it yet as im testing this code. and the values sent to store in the php variable is not input by users.

Comment: Seriously, regardless of testing it's vital that you sanitise all SQL statements, especially when posting code online where others will see it - lead by example.

Comment: Okay. i will edit it then. :( still dosen't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $check is a boolean (or evaluates to a boolean value in comparisons):

```
if($check == true){
```

or better, just:

```
if ($check) {
```

Comment: The `===` comparison is certain to fail, as the incoming variable *is* a string (or NULL).

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to check for `true`, rather than `'true'` - you're looking for a string of text that happens to spell true, not the boolean true/false.

Comment: Input variables coming from $_GET happen to be strings, always. Comparing against the boolean constant will only work by accident.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what $check contains.. please provide more information.
in **general** it will work:

```
if (!empty($check)) {
    $insert  = "INSERT INTO tab (id,url) VALUES ('$id','$url')";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

if **$check** is a boolean just do like this:

```
if ( $check ) {
    $insert  = "INSERT INTO tab (id,url) VALUES ('$id','$url')";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

and perheps it works:

```
if ( $check == TRUE ) {
```

Comment: And what if `$check` is `'false'`? :)

Comment: I had edited my answer. If 'true' or 'false' is a boolean verification in need, and forget my answer above..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the if statement to:

```
if ($check) {
```

What you want to do is evaluate it as a boolean, so you need to treat it as one. The sticking point here is what possible values `$check` can have as it comes from the client - the best thing to do it to have the client use `1` for true and `0` for false.

It's probably worth you reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). Note that almost any string value (which is what you will get from `$_GET` and `$_POST`) will evaluate to true - the place you can easily get caught out here is the `'false'` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you get from the browser is iffy. There is nasty people about,

sanitize the inputs.